# bash: command not found issue ( sshpass )

Tags: bash, shell, sshpass

I have `machine A` and `machine B`. From my `local machine X` , I wanted to run a bash script , Which would connect to `Machine A` and Then to `Machine B` to check package version on `Machine B`.

Right now , I have two or more packages installed on `Machine B`.

Single Package Version Check :

```
sshpass -p 'Password' ssh admin@A.A.A.A -p 30025  "sshpass -p 'Password' ssh B.B.B.B "dpkg -s env.ns | grep -E 'Version|Package' | tr '\n' ',' |sed 's/,$/\n/'""
```

Result :

```
Package: env.ns,Version: 51.0.0n
```

Multiple Package Check :

```
sshpass -p 'Password' ssh admin@A.A.A.A -p 30025  "sshpass -p 'Password' ssh B.B.B.B "dpkg -s env.ns | grep -E 'Version|Package' | tr '\n' ',' |sed 's/,$/\n/' && dpkg -s agent.ns | grep -E 'Version|Package' | tr '\n' ',' |sed 's/,$/\n/'""
```

Result :

```
Package: env.ns,Version: 51.0.0n
-bash: dpkg: command not found
```

I cannot able to get the package version of the second one. Using `sshpass`, Can we pass multiple commands to run on host machine ?

Expected Result :

```
Package: env.ns,Version: 51.0.0
Package: agent.ns,Version: 51.0.0
```

Comment: Set up private-key authentication, and use `ssh -J admin@A.A.A.A:30025 B.B.B.B 'dpkg ...'`.

Comment: You have a quote-nesting problem in *both* commands.  You need to escape the inner pair of double quotes in each command for them to have the meaning you appear to intend.  I'm uncertain whether that will completely solve your problem, but it will certainly be a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `';'` instead of `'&&'`

```
sshpass -p 'Password' ssh admin@A.A.A.A -p 30025  "sshpass -p 'Password' ssh B.B.B.B "dpkg -s env.ns | grep -E 'Version|Package' | tr '\n' ',' |sed 's/,$/\n/' ; dpkg -s agent.ns | grep -E 'Version|Package' | tr '\n' ',' |sed 's/,$/\n/'""
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything behind the && is executed as a separate command.
Maybe you can try brace expansion: add both commands in curly braces like this `{command1, command2}` (not sure if this will work)

If the brace expansion doesn't work you'll have to repeat the command.